# A congruence of sum of kth powers of first p-1 numbers

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, contest-math

> **Problem:** For $k < p-1$ where $p$ is an odd prime and $k$ is a natural number, prove that  $$1^k+2^k+\cdots+(p-1)^k \equiv 0 \mod p.$$

My attempt: It's obvious for odd $k$, as we can pair the terms 1 with $p-q$ and so on. But I can't come up with a proof for even $k$. It seems like pairing idea used for odd for odd will not work as for a given summand its negative residue may not be present not be be present.  For example for primes of the form $4k+3$, $-1$ will not be present  but 1 is present.

So, it looks like we will need some kind of expansions.

I found this problem as an unproved lemma, in the proof of an IMO shortlist problem.

I only know elementary number theory.

Please help me.